# How do I get the direction of a callout arrow on a msoShapeRoundedRectangularCallout?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I am saving out images of shapes in a presentation and I can't figure out how to get the distance and direction of the callout arrow on a rounded corner rectangle with a callout.  The MSOautoshape 106: Yellow corner is top left position, but image saved image has offset due to callout.

[image]

```
var tempString = shape.AutoShapeType.ToString();
if ( tempString.Contains("Callout")){
Debug.WriteLine(shape.Callout.Angle);
}
```

This code throws an error that it only works with "LINE" callouts.  I'm kinda at a loss on how to solve this one.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Callout` property is, indeed, only valid for "line callouts":

[image]

The kind of shape shown in the question uses the `Adjustments` property to read/control the settings to a Shape:

```
Word.Shape shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes[1];
Word.Adjustments = adj = shp.Adjustments;
for (int p = 1; p<=adj.Count; p++)
{
    Debug.Print(adj.Item[p].ToString());
}
```

It's necessary to experiment with the specific `Shape` and various generated settings to determine what the various values signify. In my tests with the specified Shape I got three adjustment values. The first appeared to indicate the angle/offset of the callout, the second the length/distance to the rectangle and the third I wasn't able to determine (was static).

From the object model language reference:

> **Type of Adjustment Valid values**
>
> **Linear** (horizontal or vertical)
>
> Generally the value 0.0 represents the left or top edge of the shape
> and the value 1.0 represents the right or bottom edge of the shape.
> Valid values correspond to valid adjustments you can make to the shape
> manually. For example, if you can only pull an adjustment handle half
> way across the shape manually, the maximum value for the corresponding
> adjustment will be 0.5. For shapes such as callouts, where the values
> 0.0 and 1.0 represent the limits of the rectangle defined by the starting and ending points of the callout line, negative numbers and
> numbers greater than 1.0 are valid values.
>
> **Radial**
>
> An adjustment value of 1.0 corresponds to the width of the shape. The maximum value is
> 0.5, or half way across the shape.
>
> **Angle**
>
> Values are expressed in degrees. If you specify a value outside the range – 180 to 180, it
> will be normalized to be within that range.